# What's the meaning of "establish" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From OALD, *entrench* is defined as:

> to establish something very firmly so that it is very difficult to change

Does *establish* here means [*to cause to be accepted or recognized*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/establish?r=66)?

Edit: I came across the word from this passage:

> Some people feel that this term is a bit negative, given the association with hunting and death, and they prefer more positive twists on the saying. Several organizations have even sponsored contests to come up with a new and more animal-friendly version of “to kill two birds with one stone.” However, the idea has become so **entrenched** in many societies that it is unlikely to fade from usage anytime soon, negative or not.

Comment: yes it does. (15)

Comment: It seems you have the OALD.  What is the definition for *establish* in there? Most dictionaries are internally consistent, so it makes sense to find the meaning of a word in the dictionary where you encountered it.

Comment: @mcalex I'm guessing *establish* is sense #4 from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/establish) *to make people accept a belief, claim, custom etc*?

Answer (score 3):

After further research and enquiry, I've come to the conclusion that the closest interpretation of *establish* in the definition of *entrench* is [*bring into being on a firm or stable basis*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/establish?s=t) or [*to cause (someone or something) to be widely known and accepted*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/establish).

Answer (score 1):

> ***Entrench***; to establish something very **firmly** so that it is very **difficult to
>   change**

Its meaning is closer to the definition of *establish* found at [no.5](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/establish?r=66) in the online dictionary.

> to bring about permanently: to establish order.

If something is **entrenched** it means in some form or another it is [**fixed**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fixed?s=t), *placed so as to be firm and not readily movable*; [**solid**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/solid?&o=100074&s=t),  *firm, sound and reliable,* **and** [**stable**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stable?s=t) (adj) able or likely to continue or last; *firmly established*; enduring or permanent.

Therefore, when the author states,

> [...] the idea has become so entrenched in many societies that it
>   is unlikely to fade from usage anytime soon, negative or not.

we understand that the idiom, to kill two birds with one stone, will continue to remain with us for a very long time, in other words it is an idiom *firmly established* in the cultural and collective memory.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the usage of the term, **to kill two birds with one stone**, is very frequent and common in the society, and is a part of the everyday language so it is unlikely to ever die despite its negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

To "entrench" is to put troops, artillery, etc. into a trench  for protection against enemy fire (military). That is, to "fortify." In this context, to "establish" something  is synonymous with to "fortify" it against change.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of "entrench", "establish" means to introduce or to make effective. To "entrench" something is to put it into force and defend it such that it cannot easily be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would go with the definition of [Oxford Learners Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/establish), where
"establish something"  means *to start or create an organization, a system, etc. that is meant to last for a long time*.

Together with the definition of "entrench" that you found, an idea that has become "entrenched" has been build up to last very long (in this case, probably has already been there very long) and thus is very difficult to change now. It is now part of tradition, so to say. Like the verb "to google" which, with its current meaning of *searching something online*  has become so entrenched in english language that it is not likely to disappear again in the near future and has been included in various dictionaries as a valid verb.